# Android widget button

Tags: android, widget

i am using [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf) tutorial to create a widget. My problem is with the buttons. In my widget there are three lines, each consists of a textview and three buttons. With the code below when user clicks on ButtonP1, ButtonP2 or ButtonP3 a toast msg should be seen with different messages. The problem is that no matter which button i click, i get the first toast msg every time ("Message for Button P1").

```
  public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";

        @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class); 
        context.startService(intent);

         RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetmain);

         Intent active = new Intent(context, HelloWidget.class);
         active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
         active.putExtra("msg", "Message for Button P1");

         PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
         remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ButtonP1, actionPendingIntent);

         Intent active2 = new Intent(context, HelloWidget.class);
         active2.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
         active2.putExtra("msg", "Message for Button P2");

         PendingIntent actionPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active2, 0);
         remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ButtonP2, actionPendingIntent2);

         Intent active3 = new Intent(context, HelloWidget.class);
         active3.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
         active3.putExtra("msg", "Message for Button P3");

         PendingIntent actionPendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active3, 0);
         remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ButtonP3, actionPendingIntent3);

         appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

   }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
        final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
        AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
        AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
        this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
        }
        } else {
          // check, if our Action was called
          if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
        String msg = "null";
        try {
        msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "msg = null");
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
          super.onReceive(context, intent);
         }

    }


}
```

I don't think the .xml file for the layout is necessary so i am not wasting space with it.

What am i missing?

**Solution**

```
Intent configIntent4 = new Intent(context, Call1.class);
         configIntent4.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);
         PendingIntent configPendingIntent4 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_FOUR, configIntent4, 0);
         remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Button01, configPendingIntent4);


         Intent configIntent5 = new Intent(context, Call2.class);
         configIntent5.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);
         PendingIntent configPendingIntent5 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_FIVE, configIntent5, 0);
         remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Button02, configPendingIntent5);


         Intent configIntent6 = new Intent(context, Call3.class);
         configIntent6.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);
         PendingIntent configPendingIntent6 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_SIX, configIntent6, 0);
         remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Button023 configPendingIntent6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0)
Parameters:
**context** The Context in which this PendingIntent should perform the broadcast.
**requestCode** Private request code for the sender (currently not used).
**intent** The Intent to be broadcast.
**flags**

You should use different requestCode.

Comment: I have already solved it, but forgot to add the solution. This time I have updated my question. Thanks anyway.